# How can I change color in a row

Tags: android, listview

How can I change color in a row in the listview if it contains the value M?

This is my display adapter, now I have all the black lines, but if you see a value in txt_turno M, I would like the corresponding line highlighted in playback mode in red.

```
public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder mHolder;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        if (child == null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            mHolder = new Holder();
            mHolder.txt_giorni = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_giorni);
            mHolder.txt_turno = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.txt_turno);
```

Comment: You need to provide more details if you expect a useful answer. Post your code (including any relevant layout file).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your `adapter's` `getView` method:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainmenu_item, parent, false);

//text in which you want to find "M"
TextView text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text);

if(text.getText().toString().contains("M"){
    rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
}
return rowView;
```

}

You also hava to definde R.color.red in res/values/colors.xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```